# Remove blank spaces on the right side of each element of a character vector in R

Tags: r

My data is

```
student_Name= c("Sachin Tendulkar        ","Virendar Shewag            ",
           "Saurav Ganguly             ")
```

I want to remove the blank spaces on the right side in R.

So that my output should be "Sachin Tendulkar","Virendar Shewag","Saurav Ganguly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_trim` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
student_Name <- str_trim(student_Name, side='right')
```

Or use `sub`

```
sub('\\s+$', '', student_Name)
#[1] "Sachin Tendulkar" "Virendar Shewag"  "Saurav Ganguly"
```